# React-query setQueryData not re-rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I've been dealing for a while with this problem and still can't tackle it.

I'm using React-query as a server state management library and I'm trying to get my UI state synchronized with my server state when a mutations occurs. Since I can use the mutation response to avoid a new API call, I'm using the setQueryData feature that React-query gives us.

The problem is that the old-data is being correctly modified (I can see it in the react-query DevTools) when a mutation is successful, but the component using it isn't being re-rendered, making my UI State not synchronized with my Server state (well, at least the user can't see the update).

Let me show some code and hope someone can give me some insights.

`Component using the query:`

```
const Detail = ({ orderId }) => {
  const { workGroups } = useWorkGroups();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const orderQueries = queryClient.getQueryData(["orders"]);
  const queryOrder = orderQueries?.find((ord) => ord.id === orderId);

// more code
```

`Component mutating the query`:

```
const Deliver = ({
  setIsModalOpened,
  artisan,
  index,
  queryQuantity,
  queryOrder,
}) => {
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(() => queryQuantity);

  const { mutate: confirmOrderDelivered } = useMutateOrderDeliveredByArtisan(
    queryOrder.id
  );

  const onSubmit = () => {
    confirmOrderDelivered(
      {
        id: queryOrder.artisan_production_orders[index].id,
        artisan: artisan.user,
        items: [
          {
            quantity_delivered: quantity,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        onSuccess: setIsModalOpened(false),
      }
    );
  };

// more code
```

`Now the mutation function (ik it's a lot of logic but I dont' want to refetch the data using invalidateQueries since we're dealing with users with a really bad internet connection). Ofc you don't need to understand each step of the fn but what it basically does is update the old queried data. In the beginning I thought it was a mutation reference problem since React using a strict comparison under the hood but I also checked it and It doesn't look like it's the problem.` :

```
{
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        queryClient.setQueryData(["orders"], (oldQueryData) => {
          let oldQueryDataCopy = [...oldQueryData];
          const index = oldQueryDataCopy.findIndex(
            (oldData) => oldData.id === orderId
          );

          let artisanProdOrders =
            oldQueryDataCopy[index].artisan_production_orders;

          let artisanProductionOrderIdx = artisanProdOrders.findIndex(
            (artProdOrd) => artProdOrd.id === data.id
          );

          artisanProdOrders[artisanProductionOrderIdx] = {
            ...artisanProdOrders[artisanProductionOrderIdx],
            items: data.items,
          };

          const totalDelivered = artisanProdOrders.reduce((acc, el) => {
            const delivered = el.items[0].quantity_delivered;
            return acc + delivered;
          }, 0);

          oldQueryDataCopy[index] = {
            ...oldQueryDataCopy[index],
            artisan_production_orders: artisanProdOrders,
            items: [
              {
                ...oldQueryDataCopy[index].items[0],
                quantity_delivered: totalDelivered,
              },
            ],
          };
          return oldQueryDataCopy;
        });
      },

      onError: (err) => {
        throw new Error(err);
      },
    }
```

And last but not least: I already checked that the oldQueryData is being correctly modified (console loging in the onSuccess fn in the mutation response) and, as I said before, the data is correctly modified in the React-query DevTools.

I know this is a lot of code and the problem seems to be complex but I really believe that it might be a really easy thing that I'm not pointing out because of how tired I already am.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I fixed it in the worst possible way imho, so I will answer this question but I really would like to read your thoughts.

It looks like the new query data setted on the expected query is re-rendering the component only if the mutation function is located in the component that we actually want to re-render.

With that in mind what I did was just colocate my mutation function in the parent component and pass it down through the child component.

Something like this:

```
const Detail = ({ orderId }) => {
  const { workGroups } = useWorkGroups();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

const { mutate: confirmOrderDelivered } = useMutateOrderDeliveredByArtisan(
    queryOrder.id
  ); ==============> THE MUTATION FN IS NOW IN THE PARENT COMPONENT

  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const orderQueries = queryClient.getQueryData(["orders"]);
  const queryOrder = orderQueries?.find((ord) => ord.id === orderId);

// more code
```

`First child`:

```
const Assigned = ({ artisan, queryOrder, index, confirmOrderDelivered }) => {

// THE IMPORTANT PART HERE IS THE PROP BEING PASSED DOWN.

 <Modal
          isOpen={isModalOpened}
          toggleModal={setIsModalOpened}
          // className="w312"
          width="80%"
          height="fit-content"
          justifyCont="unset"
          alignItems="unset"
        >
          <Deliver
            setIsModalOpened={setIsModalOpened}
            artisan={artisan}
            queryQuantity={quantity}
            queryOrder={queryOrder}
            index={index}
            confirmOrderDelivered={confirmOrderDelivered} => HERE
          />
        </Modal>
```

`Component that actually needs the mutation fn`:

```
const Deliver = ({
  setIsModalOpened,
  artisan,
  index,
  queryQuantity,
  queryOrder,
  confirmOrderDelivered,
}) => {
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(() => queryQuantity);

  const onSubmit = () => {
    confirmOrderDelivered( => HERE.
      {
        id: queryOrder.artisan_production_orders[index].id,
        artisan: artisan.user,
        items: [
          {
            quantity_delivered: quantity,
          },
        ],
      }
    );
  };
```

Comment: I think the problem is more related to how you perform the update. Are you sure that the update is immutable ? Maybe you can try to reproduce the problem in a codesandbox with a simpler structure?

Comment: I'm having terrible experience with making optimistic updates, and manually updating my cache or doing invalidate or refetch and waiting miracles to happened, so I can get proper refresh. All my refresh it's because I'm forcing the component to rerender, because of other things like snackbar or some other alert...

Answer (score 4):

You can't mutate any prop.

You always need to create new versions of the objects and props and use destructuring.

**Example**

```
queryClient.setQueryData([QUERY_KEYS.MYKEY], (old) => {

   const myArray = [...old.myArray];

  return {
   ...old,

   // WRONG 
   myArray[0].name: 'text1',

   // CORRECT 
   myArray[0]: {
          ...myArray[0],
           name: 'text1'
   }

}})
```

Comment: Would you point out where in my code I made that mistake? It's some basic react stuff so I already know how to perform state updates in these kind of cases. Of course mistakes can be made.

Although I already answered the question pointing out how I solved it, though it was kinda tricky imo.

Comment: hi @FrancoAlemandi my answer was not for you specifically, it's common on stack overflow to give different possible answers to a problem. 

In my case the solution was where I added here, hopefully, it will help someone else in the future. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when using oldData in the setQueryData function to generate newData, it is important to avoid modifying the original data. Modifying the old data can lead to issues and prevent your code from functioning correctly. In your code, oldQueryData is an array containing objects, and the line `let oldQueryDataCopy = [...oldQueryData];` only creates a shallow copy of the array, not the individual items within it.

To ensure proper functionality, you can use `let oldQueryDataCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldQueryData))` instead of `let oldQueryDataCopy = [...oldQueryData];`. This deep clone method effectively duplicates the array and its contents, preventing unintended modifications and ensuring correct operation of your code.